# Division not working properly in Swift

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
println(Double(2/5))
```

When I run this, it prints out

```
0.0
```

How can I fix this? I want it to come out to `0.4`. It there some issue with the rounding?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you're not converting to a `Double` until after you've done integer division between two integers.  Let's take a look at order of operations.  We start at the inside and move outward.

- Perform integer division between the integer `2` and the integer `5`, which results in the integer `0`.
- Create a double from the integer `0`, which creates the double `0.0`.
- Call `description` on the double `0.0`, which returns the string `"0.0"`
- Call `println` on the string `"0.0"`

---

We can fix this by calling the `Double` constructor on each side of the division *before* we divide them.

```
println((Double(2)/Double(5)))
```

Now the order of operations is:

- Convert the integer `2` to the floating point `2.0`
- Convert the integer `5` to the floating point `5.0`
- Perform floating point division between these floating point numbers, resulting in `0.4`
- Call `description` on the floating point number `0.4`, which returns the string `"0.4"`.
- Call `println` on the string `"0.4"`.

---

Note that it's not strictly necessary to convert both sides of the division to `Double`.

And as long as we're dealing with literals, we can just write `println(2.0/5.0)`.

We could also get away with writing `println((2 * 1.0)/5)` which should now interpret all of our literals as floating point (as we've multiplied it by a floating point).

As long as either side of a math operating is a floating point type, the integer literal will be interpreted as a floating point type by Swift, but in my opinion, it's far better to explicitly convert our types so that we're excruciatingly clear on exactly what we want to happen.  So let's get all of our numbers into the same type and be explicitly clear what we actually want.

---

If we're dealing with literals, we can add `.0` to them to force them as floating point numbers:

```
println(2.0/5.0)
```

If we're doing with variables, we can use a constructor:

```
let myTwoInt: Int = 2
let myFiveInt: Int = 5

println((Double(myTwoInt)/Double(myFiveInt))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your issue is that you are dividing two integers which normally will return an integer.
I had a similar issue in java, adding a .0 to one or the other integers or converting either to a double by using the double function should fix it.

It's a feature of typed languages that creates a result of the same type as the values being divided.

Answer (score 2):

Digits is correct about the cause; instead of the approach you're taking, try this:

```
print(2.0 / 5.0)
```